# Is there a postgreSQL foreign table wrapper that will access zipped csv files?

Tags: postgresql, compression, foreign-data-wrapper

I'm interested in storing long term static data outside of the database, ideally in compressed files that are dynamically uncompressed when accessed.  I am currently using the existing file_fdw for some purposed, but would really like to be able to compress the data.

We currently use 9.3.

Comment: Should be easy to write some code for.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be such a wrapper [here](https://github.com/dialogbox/py_csvgz_fdw). It requires [Multicorn](http://multicorn.org/), so you'll have to install that first.

I have not tried it and don't know how well it works.

Alternatively, did you consider using compression at the storage level?

Comment: neat suggestion to compress at the storage level: https://serverfault.com/questions/617648/transparent-compression-filesystem-in-conjunction-with-ext4